# Is the query result set of the select sub-query static in a T-Sql Insert Into select..?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

source_tbl:
  email_addr, role

target_tbl:
  email_addr, roles

source_tbl can have many email addresses. 
target_tbl can have one distinct email address (the role in source_tbl is consolidated into roles in target_tbl - just fyi)

My concern is not duplicating email address in target_tbl (no constraints are in place by dba setup)

I have a suspicion that the the sub-query inside a Insert into Select is done once, and that result set is then used by the insert. If this is the case then a query like this won't work:

```
insert into target_tbl 
 ( email_addr, roles)
select 
 src.email_addr,
 src.role
from source_tbl src
where src.email_address not in ( select email_addr from target_tbl)
```

can't find anything that confirms my suspicion, checking to see if someone can point me to documentation that gives me this confirmation

Comment: Could you provide a little info about the roles.  I think you might be able to pivot and merge and there a handful of other solutions that would take a many rows down to a 1 row relationship.  Could you provide some sample data in your question so we can target an answer for you.  Hint: You can also look at your execution plan to see if its looping per row or if its doing a single lookup from target_tbl.  I suspect this query is not RBAR.

Comment: Why do you need documentation of something you can easily confirm by testing yourself?

Comment: Thank you for the pivot lead - that was another problem I was going to come across after my initial question @MattA.

Comment: I've been seeing the results of my query in my data. I want to know the details of why the query was running the way it is for understanding. Better to know why a think does what it does rather than just using a thing.  @TabAlleman

Comment: So ask a new question about how to achieve your desired result. The original question you had here is about the static-ness or otherwise of the sub query result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking whether the following sub query is re-evaluated for each row, and so takes into account email addresses previously added by the same statement?

```
 where src.email_address not in ( select email_addr from target_tbl)
```

If so the answer is "no".

It will be evaluated at the start and spooled somewhere as a result of [Halloween Protection](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/halloween-problem-part-1) (unless SQL Server manages to come up with a plan that guarantees these semantics without a spool but the answer is still the same).

So if the `SELECT` query returns, say, 3 rows for abc@dfg.com and that email address doesn't already exist in the target table all three rows will be inserted.

You can either change the `SELECT` to only pick one row per email or add a unique constraint to the table with `ignore_dup_key` on to just preserve the first (arbitrary) one encountered. Likely the first option is more useful as it gives you control over which one is kept.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed